# How can I stop media player when other media player app starts?

Tags: android

I want to stop media player when some other media player applications start.
I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add listener for AudioFocusChange.
Refer: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener.html

Answer (score 1):

I've done the similar thing in a project where when my app starts playing, Google Play Music pause and vice versa.

```
AudioManager am = null;

// Request focus for music stream and pass AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener
// implementation reference
int result = am.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 
                AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

if(result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED)
{
    // Play
}

// Implements AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener

@Override
public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) 
{
    if(focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT)
    {
        // Pause
    }
    else if(focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN)
    {
        // Resume
    }
    else if(focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS)
    {
        // Stop or pause depending on your need
    }
}
```